# API to Rank blog articles

Tags: twitter, social-networking, blogs, ranking, popularity

I would like to know if there is any easy way to rank blog articles by counting how many times they have been retweeted / digg'ed / buzz'ed and if there is an existing api for it.
The idea would be to keep important 'stories' at the top of the blog timeline.

Comment: There is no connection with Java, so I removed the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postrank  offers a [Datamining API](http://data.postrank.com/) that has the functionality that your are looking for,but you have to pay for it.